# Why conversion do not appear in real time?

Tags: google-analytics

Why do I not see conversion sent by my backend in tab Real-Time > conversions on google analytics?
I am making an HTTP post request to `www.google-analytics.com/collect` with the following data:

Transaction:

```
v=1&tid=UA-XXX&cid=faw5242fa9851829581&t=transaction&ti=52525235brgg54&tr=21370.00&cu=PLN
```

And then one Item:

```
v=1&tid=UA-XXX&cid=faw5242fa9851829581&t=item&ti=52525235brgg54&in=sofaFromBackend&ip=21370.00&iq=1&cu=PLN
```

After 24 hours I see them in the Conversions > Ecommerce tab.
Of course, I am writing about Google Analytics Universal

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing real-time conversions with transactions. The convertion is the goal that require to be settings. You can't see transaction in Real Time.